# Access a page of one war file from another war file?

Tags: java, maven, glassfish

**NOTE:** I cannot package them into an EAR. Some constraints here.

I have 2 war files.

help.war and helpConnect.war

Both are placed in the same domain of GlassFish server.

From the index page of help.war am accessing a page in helpConnect.war like this..

```
<a href="helpConnect/HelpInternal/index.htm">Help Internal</a>
```

This isn't working because when I try to access on the server, the URL its trying to access is like this..

```
http://localhost:8080/help/helpConnect/HelpInternal/index.htm
```

However, since helpConnect is a totally different war file I need the URL like this

```
http://localhost:8080/helpConnect/HelpInternal/index.htm
```

Any idea how to get this around?

Answer (score 2):

You're using a relative path. You need an absolute path:

```
<a href="/helpConnect/HelpInternal/index.htm">Help Internal</a>
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you much..an additional slash made an entire difference. :)